# How to use selenium capabilities for Firefox in splinter?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, splinter

I'm using python splinter which is built on selenium, i want to use another webdriver for firefox as starting from version 47 firefox changed the webdriver as per below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver

splinter docs says you can pass capabilities argument to use selenium capabilities

```
from splinter import Browser 
browser = Browser(‘firefox’, capabilities={‘acceptSslCerts’: True})
```

http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/master/drivers/firefox.html#how-to-use-selenium-capabilities-for-firefox

but when using testing i got the error

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capabilities'

also class `splinter.driver.webdriver.firefox.WebDriver` doesn't contain capabilites, although in splinter doc it contains it, i have the latest version what am i missing?!

```
__init__(self, profile=None, extensions=None, user_agent=None, profile_preferences=None, fullscreen=False, wait_time=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the documentation generated for the *`master` branch* of the `splinter` project.

For `capabilities` to work, you need to uninstall `splinter` and install it [*directly from github*](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter):

```
$ pip uninstall splinter
$ pip install git+https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter#master
```

(worked for me).

Comment: this solved the problem, thanks, would you please explain more what is master version?

Comment: @Amr in this case, this is a git branch which "represents" a development version of the package..